# What is the connector on kinesis keyboard board called?

Tags: connector, keyboard

The connector on board of kinesis advantage pro keyboard (for usb and rj cables).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Standard PCB header with shroud and interlock , keyed, 0.1" space 7 pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [B7B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/B7B-PH-K-S-LF-SN/926616) + [PHR-7](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-7/608603) + [SPH-002T-P0.5L](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SPH-002T-P0-5L/1300246) from JST manufacturer for the right connector (that circled in red on the question photo).

And it is [B9B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/B9B-PH-K-S-LF-SN/926618) + [PHR-9](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-9/608601) + [SPH-002T-P0.5L](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SPH-002T-P0-5L/1300246) for the left connector.

I bought them and they fit perfectly (but I didn't crimp it yet).

Specification for JST PH connector series: https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf

Thanks to @Kevin for pointing out the JST manufacturer.

P.S.: USB cable is probably a "Copartner E119932".

On this new photo there are original Kinesis Advantage Pro keyboard cable with connector on the left and new one (bought by me) on the right:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a JST SH Connector. JST is the "brand"/designer.

Here's the digi-key part. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B7B-XH-A(LF)(SN)/455-2252-ND/1651050 Please note that your connector may be a chinese variant or knockoff, but this shouldn't matter for you.

Here's how you can search for connector types: http://www.digikey.com/en/resources/connectors/rectangular-connectors

Comment: would you happen to know what the male connector is called? Also, if you notice there is the other connector on the left side, would you happen to know what that might be called as well? Thanks.

Comment: @Munib, it seems like "B9B-XH-A(LF)(SN)" + "EHR-9" for left connector and "B7B-XH-A(LF)(SN)" + "EHR-7" for right connector. URLs: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/B9B-XH-A-LF-SN/1651042 https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/EHR-9/527231 https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/B7B-XH-A(LF)(SN)/1651050 https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/EHR-7/527229

Comment: @Munib, I was wrong. It is "B9B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)" + "PHR-9" for left connector and "B7B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)" + "PHR-7" for right connector. And "SPH-002T-P0.5L" connector contact for both. I bought them and they fit perfectly. I will crimp them later and add a detailed answer.